# how to hover HTML same ID different class?

Tags: html, css

```css
       #menu .bar .a:hover  #menu .item .m1{
            display : block;
        }

   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="bar">
        <div class="a">a</div>
        <div class="b">b</div>
        <div class="c">c</div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="item">item
        <div class="m1">m1</div>
        <div class="m2">m2</div>
        <div class="m3">m3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="contents">contents</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i'v tried lots of times but can't get the results

[image]

**if i hover box a, i want to see box m1**

Please help me ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ need help ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: You need Javascript for that

Comment: for hover to work, the elements has to be either `siblings` or `child`, in you case the element `m1` is outside of element `a` class, so as @Gerard said either you have to change html elements or use JS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu:hover + .item{
  display: block;
}

.item{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

#menu{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <div class="menu a">a</div>
      <div class="item m1">m1</div>
      <div class="menu b">b</div>
      <div class="item m2">m2</div>
      <div class="menu c">c</div>
      <div class="item m3">m3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this what do you want to get?

**Edit**: You can add js code between script tags at the bottom of your html document.

```js
  let bar = document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0];
  let items = document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0];
  for (const item of bar.children){
    item.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
      let index = Array.from(bar.children).indexOf(event.currentTarget);
      items.children[index].style.display = 'block';
    });

    item.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
      for (const item of items.children){
        item.style.display = 'none';
      };
  });
  }
```

```css
.item > *{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="a">a</div>
          <div class="b">b</div>
          <div class="c">c</div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="item">
          <div class="m1">m1</div>
          <div class="m2">m2</div>
          <div class="m3">m3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="contents">contents</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: having class "bar" and class "item" in different section is not possible??

Comment: If you are limited only to html/css then it's not possible.

Comment: I edited my answer with possible solution using js.